# sheets stored in an array and paste them as values to new workbook, maintaining sheets' names and order

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write this little macro to copy several sheets stored in an array and paste them as values to new workbook, maintaining sheets' names and order. I've found some solutions but not exactly matching my situation.

This is for excel macro where we try sending dashboard thru mail along with attachment but need to added sheet only paste values with same formatting

```
 Option Explicit

Sub Send_Email_With_snapshot()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary")
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
Worksheets(Array("Calculation", "Retailer Wise_Data", "TM Wise", "Channel_Base")).Copy
    Worksheets("Calculation").Range("a1:Ax54").Copy
    Worksheets("Calculation").Range("a1:Ax54").PasteSpecial _
    Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
With ActiveWorkbook
     .SaveAs Filename:="E:\Automation\New folder\" & "RAEO_Dashboard_MTD.xlsx", FileFormat:=51
     .Close savechanges:=True
         Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim lr As Integer

lr = sh.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

sh.Range("A1:T120").Select

With Selection.Parent.MailEnvelope.Item
    .to = "xyz.com"
    .cc = ""
    .Subject = sh.Range("AN14").Value
    .attachments.Add "D:\RAEO_Dashboard_MTD.xlsx"
    .send

End With
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.Save
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't sure if you meant when you wrote "with same formatting". If by that you mean cells formatting (eg. color, size, borders, visible/hidden propertie, etc.) then I added another section at the end of this answer to address that. However, if you only need number formats to stay the same, here is how you could do it.

## Paste values and number formats

The 2 key elements here are:

- To use `.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats` to paste values and number formats at the same time.
- Use a **For loop** to go over your array of sheets.

Implemented this would look like this:

```
Sub CopySheetsValuesAndNumberFormats()

    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll 'In case you have Pivot Tables to refresh

    Dim ListOfSheets() As Variant
    ListOfSheets = Array("Calculation", "Retailer Wise_Data", "TM Wise", "Channel_Base") 'Example list based on the question

    Dim SourceWorkbook As Workbook
    Set SourceWorkbook = ThisWorkbook 'Or Workbooks("Workbook Name")

    Dim DestinationWorkbook As Workbook
    Set DestinationWorkbook = Workbooks.Add

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(ListOfSheets) To UBound(ListOfSheets)

        Dim SourceSheet As Worksheet
        Set SourceSheet = SourceWorkbook.Worksheets(ListOfSheets(i))

        Dim DestinationSheet As Worksheet
        Set DestinationSheet = DestinationWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=DestinationWorkbook.Worksheets(DestinationWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)) 'Insert in last position
        DestinationSheet.Name = SourceSheet.Name

        Dim SourceRange As Range
        Set SourceRange = SourceSheet.UsedRange

        Dim DestinationRange As Range
        Set DestinationRange = DestinationSheet.Range(SourceRange.Address)

        'Paste values and number formats
        SourceRange.Copy
        DestinationRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Next i

    'Delete initial sheets
    For i = 1 To 3
        On Error Resume Next
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        DestinationWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet" & i).Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next i

End Sub
```

## Paste values and cells formatting

In order to copy the formatting, you are going to have to copy from all `Cells` as opposed to from the `UsedRange` in the first section of this answer. The reason is that some columns might have some formatting that apply to all the cells inside a column, but not all these cells will be part of the `UsedRange`.

The only part of the code that you need to replace from the code above is the one starting with "Paste values and number formats". You would need to replace this part with the following:

```
        'Paste values and cells formatting
        SourceSheet.Cells.Copy
        DestinationSheet.Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
        SourceRange.Copy
        DestinationRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: Thank a ton, sir .. code Is working fine only need some format missing in like hiding column now is visible and not autofit properly, cells merge & column width and height not adjust Please help on this also i m new in VBA.. 

will thankful always.

Comment: @Shaf3067  I see. I had misunderstood what you meant by "same formatting". I made a change to my answer. Hope that solves the issue.